# org-mode babel sh script + escaped(?) ~ char for home directory?

Tags: emacs, sh, org-mode, org-babel

I have this small **sh** script under org-mode babel:

```
#+NAME: testHomeDir 
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :var directory="./"
set -e
cd $directory
ls | head -5
#+END_SRC
```

Note: `set -e` is there to stop the script as soon as an error occurs.

The script works well with full path:

```
#+CALL: testHomeDir("/home/picaud/Temp")
```

> ```
> #+RESULTS:
> :RESULTS:
> current issues.pdf
> AnnotatedPDF
> Bitbucket
> compareScript.wls
> Data
> :END:
> ```

However when used with `~` (my home directory) it does not work anymore:

```
#+CALL: testHomeDir("~/Temp")
```

I get the

> sh: 4: cd: can't cd to ~/Temp

error message.

Please also note that

```
#+CALL: testHomeDir("\~/Temp")
#+CALL: testHomeDir("\\~/Temp")
```

do not work too.

I guess that the `~` character is escaped somewhere (in Emacs? in sh?)...

**My question is: how to fix that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ~ is not being expanded by the shell because it is being set within Emacs and is the literal string '~'. In order to get the expansion you need to run it through eval:

```
directory=$(eval echo $directory)
```

before you try to use it.